# Can't request route with cypressJS

Tags: cypress

I try to simply request data from a route within a cypress test:

```
it("Then it works", () => {

    cy.server()           
    cy.route({
        method: 'GET',     
        url: '/users/1',    
        response: true      
    })
    axios.defaults.headers.common = {
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
    }

    axios.get("http://localhost:8080/users/1").then(response => {
        console.log(response)
        expect(response.body).to.equal(true)
    }).catch(error => console.log(error))
})
```

All I get ist "Error: Request failed with status code 404" thus it seems that the route is not available for axios. In my cypress.json I've configured the base URL as:

```
{
  "baseUrl": "http://localhost:8080"
}
```

From my point of view it is basically the example from the [documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/network-requests.html#Requests) and I can't figure out why it is wrong. I know, that cypress can only handle XMLHttpRequests, so I configured this for axios and I want to simulate with the acios a call that usually happens within my SPA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making the calls from inside the test, while `cy.route` is helpful to intercept the front-end requests. More: remember that (from the Cypress docs)

> Cypress commands are enqueued and run asynchronously

What I mean: it's the front-end app that must call `axios.get`, not you directly from the test.

You can do:

- `cy.visit` a page that has `axios` globally defined
- let the call start from the front-end

```
it("Then it works", () => {

    cy.server()           
    cy.route({
        method: 'GET',     
        url: '/users/1',    
        response: true      
    })
    cy.visit("http://localhost:8000"); // replace it with your working app
    cy.window().then(win => {
        axios.defaults.headers.common = {
            "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
        }

        axios.get("http://localhost:8080/users/1").then(response => {
            console.log(response)
            expect(response.body).to.equal(true)
        }).catch(error => console.log(error))
    })
})
```

and everything should work. If not, please share a GitHub repo with it and I'll help you with that